# Why are "magnetic field lines" called "lines of force" when they are perpendicular to the direction of force?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, terminology, vector-fields

Why are "magnetic field lines" called "lines of force" when they are actually  perpendicular to direction of force (Lorentz force,cross product)?

It makes sense to call "field lines" as "lines of force" in case of fields like gravitational, electrostatic, etc., but not in magnetic force it seems to me.

Comment: I wonder why people downvoted this question. The user gave a correct reason why not to call them "lines of force". Was it only because it's a duplicate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

“Lines of force” is a terminology given to the visual representation of a field. The concept of “lines of force” was developed by **Michael Faraday**, this [wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_of_force) says:

> Lines of force originated with Michael Faraday, whose theory holds that all of reality is made up of force itself.

Also, according to [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/line%20of%20force) the term “lines of force” was first used in 1837, which we all know was the period of **Michael Faraday**.

“Lines of force” represent those things which *causes* the force, they need not to point in the direction of force. If in a electrostatic field produced by a positive point charge, we put a negative point charge we know the force will act directly opposite to the direction of *arrows* which represents the “lines of force” and for positive charge the force will be in same direction. So, considering the previous two examples we can infer that “lines of force” don’t represent the direction of force but rather the direction of field which they represent.

> Why are magnetic field lines called lines of force when actually they are perpendicular to direction of force (Lorentz force,cross product)?

It is because they are not meant to represent the direction of the force.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

The gravitational force on a point mass will be along the tangent to the gravitational field line at that point. The electrostatic force will be along the direction of tangent for a positive point charge and opposite to the direction of tangent for a negative point charge of the electric field line at that particular position.

In a similar way, the magnetic field lines denote the direction of magnetic force on a hypothetical magnetic charge (magnetic monopole). The direction of force is along the tangent for a positive magnetic charge (north pole) and opposite for a negative magnetic charge (south pole). This explains why the alternate term for field lines "lines of force" is named in that way.

The Lorentz force, given by $\vec F=q(\vec v\times\vec B)$ is the force exerted on a moving **electric** charge by a magnetic field.

Comment: But magnetic monopoles are not discovered so far. So as far as we are concerned the field lines will not exert "force" on any real physical object.

Comment: @HrishabhNayal: I know that :) That's why I mentioned "**hypothetical** magnetic charge".

Comment: But still that makes the name look erroneous to me. Sorry, if i sound too skeptical